# gfortran: error: -fuse-linker-plugin is not supported in the compilation

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, gfortran

[FLEXPART](https://www.flexpart.eu/) is a Fortran-based model for the simulation of the emission, transportation, and dispersion of atmospheric species.

In the compilation of the [source code](https://www.flexpart.eu/downloads/51), I met a strange error.

My makefile is uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CcqD5yijMWAM7rTmJgxI1XJ7NJESLs59/view?usp=sharing). 
The error shows like this:

```
/disk2/hyf/lib/gcc-4.9.4/bin/gfortran -o FP_gfs_gfortran par_mod.o          com_mod.o conv_mod.o              hanna_mod.o interpol_mod.o          cmapf_mod.o unc_mod.o               oh_mod.o xmass_mod.o             flux_mod.o point_mod.o             outg_mod.o random_mod.o advance.o     initialize.o writeheader.o      writeheader_txt.o writeheader_surf.o        assignland.o part0.o        gethourlyOH.o caldate.o               partdep.o coordtrafo.o            psih.o raerod.o         readcommand.o drydepokernel.o         readreceptors.o erf.o                   readavailable.o ew.o          readreleases.o readdepo.o psim.o            outgrid_init.o outgrid_init_nest.o photo_O1D.o      readlanduse.o interpol_wind.o         readoutgrid.o interpol_all.o          readpaths.o getrb.o getrc.o getvdep.o               readspecies.o interpol_misslev.o scalev.o pbl_profile.o           readOHfield.o juldate.o interpol_vdep.o         interpol_rain.o hanna.o                 wetdepokernel.o mean.o                  wetdepo.o hanna_short.o           windalign.o hanna1.o gridcheck_nests.o readwind_nests.o        calcpar_nests.o verttransform_nests.o   interpol_all_nests.o interpol_wind_nests.o   interpol_misslev_nests.o interpol_vdep_nests.o   interpol_rain_nests.o readageclasses.o calcfluxes.o            fluxoutput.o qvsat.o                 skplin.o convect43c.o sort2.o                 distance.o centerofmass.o          plumetraj.o openouttraj.o           calcpv.o calcpv_nests.o          distance2.o clustering.o            interpol_wind_short.o interpol_wind_short_nests.o shift_field_0.o shift_field.o openreceptors.o readoutgrid_nest.o writeheader_nest.o writeheader_nest_surf.o wetdepokernel_nest.o drydepokernel_nest.o    zenithangle.o ohreaction.o            getvdep_nests.o initial_cond_calc.o     initial_cond_output.o dynamic_viscosity.o     get_settling.o initialize_cbl_vel.o   re_initialize_particle.o cbl.o          netcdf_output_mod.o releaseparticles.o  partoutput.o conccalc.o init_domainfill.o   concoutput.o timemanager.o FLEXPART.o readpartpositions.o partoutput_short.o concoutput_nest.o boundcond_domainfill.o redist.o concoutput_surf.o    concoutput_surf_nest.o getfields.o calcpar_gfs.o          readwind_gfs.o richardson_gfs.o       verttransform_gfs.o obukhov_gfs.o          gridcheck_gfs.o convmix_gfs.o          calcmatrix_gfs.o -I/disk2/hyf/lib/grib_api/include -I/disk2/hyf/lib/netcdf-4.6.1/include -I/disk2/hyf/lib/hdf5/include -O2  -g -m64 -mcmodel=medium -fconvert=little-endian -frecord-marker=4 -fmessage-length=0 -flto=jobserver -O2  -mtune=native -fuse-linker-plugin   -L/disk2/hyf/lib/grib_api/lib -L/disk2/hyf/lib/jasper/lib -L/disk2/hyf/lib/netcdf-4.6.1/lib -L/disk2/hyf/lib/hdf5/lib -lgrib_api_f90 -lgrib_api -lm -ljasper -lnetcdff   
gfortran: error: -fuse-linker-plugin is not supported in this configuration
make: *** [FP_gfs_gfortran] Error 1
```

In the compilation path, all the *.o file can be generated from *.f90 files, while the error shows that there is some problem with the flag `-fuse-linker-plugin`

```
#My computer system
$uname -a
Linux Xiehost 2.6.18-348.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jan 8 17:53:53 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux   

$gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/disk2/hyf/lib/gcc-4.9.4/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.4/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.4/configure --prefix=/disk2/hyf/lib/gcc-4.9.4 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.4 (GCC)
```

I don't know how to fix this problem (**-fuse-linker-plugin is not supported in the compilation**).  Any advice or tips would be appreciated!

### PS

Thanks for yours' comments. I learned from webste [Explain Linux commands](https://www.cleancss.com/explain-command/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc/67170).

> This option is enabled by default when LTO support in GCC is enabled and GCC was configured for use  with a linker supporting plugins (GNU ld 2.21 or newer or gold).

However, the GNU binutils in my computer is V2.17. Therefore, I updated the binutils, and re-compile GCC. Then, this issue can be fixed.

Comment: Have considered removing -fuse-linker-plugin from FFLAGS in the Makefile?

Comment: This is likely related to the way gcc/gfortran was configured and built. See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-04/msg00225.html for instance. How was gcc configured, built and installed on your machine?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl. Thanks for your comments. I re-installed the binutils, and gcc compiler to fix this problem.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks for your reply. Since the -fuse-linker-plugin was essential for the model, I need to add this flag.

Comment: @HanZhengzu Should I write an answer?

Comment: @Pierre de Buyl. If it is convenient, you can post the answer which would be useful for those guys with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to the way gcc/gfortran was configured and built.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-04/msg00225.html for instance.

Make sure to build gcc with LTO enabled and use a recent enough linker (the "ld" program, part of binutils).